# x axis unit value changes not reflecting on graph

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, chart.jsv3

I am trying to change unit of x axis time scale on dropdown change but graph is not displaying as per the changed unit. Below is the code where this.unit is 'minute' or 'hour' or 'day' or 'week'

```
 this.lineChartOptions.scales.x = {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: this.unit,
          displayFormats: {
            minute: 'mm:ss',
            hour: 'HH:mm',
            day: 'MMM dd',
            week: 'MMM dd',
            month: 'MMM dd',
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'dd MMM hh:mm',
        },
      };
```

Tried to change `linChartOptions`, I can see the updated value in console for the unit but x axis labels are not formatting as per changed unit. It is taking initial value only.

Comment: Note: I am updating chart with chart.update().  I can see graph is updated for lineChartData but not for the lineChartOptions